# Difference between Fact and Theory? - xUnit.net

Tags: c#, xunit.net, autofixture

I'm new to xUnit.net and AutoFixture.

I'm currently working on a "testproject" to get familiar with xUnit.net and Autofixture.
There is one little thing I don't understand.

What is the difference between `[Fact]` and `[Theory, AutoMoqData]`?

Could you please tell me if the following two pieces of code are equal?
I'm asking this because the Test succeeds with both, but I want to learn it the right way.

```
[Fact]
public void UpdateVersionWillUpdateCorrectlyInRepository()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var contract = fixture.Create<VersionContract>();
    var version = fixture.Create<Version>();

    fixture.Freeze<Mock<IContractMapper>>()
        .Setup(r => r.Map(contract)).Returns(version);

    var repMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<VersionRepository>>();

    var sut = fixture.Create<VersionManagementService>();

    sut.UpdateVersion(contract);

    repMock.Verify(r => r.UpdateVersion(version));
}
```

and

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void UpdateVersionWillUpdateCorrectlyInRepository(
    VersionContract contract,
    Version version,
    [Frozen]Mock<IContractMapper> mapMock,
    [Frozen]Mock<VersionRepository> repMock,
    VersionManagementService sut)
{
    mapMock.Setup(r => r.Map(contract)).Returns(version);

    sut.UpdateVersion(contract);

    repMock.Verify(r => r.UpdateVersion(version));
}
```

What makes me think that there is a difference are the Keywords `[Fact]` and `[Theory]`.

I'm assuming that the `[Theory]` Keywords tells the xUnit.net framework that the supplied data comes from somewhere, where somewhere is Autofixture. Whereas `[Fact]` tells xUnit nothing about the origin of the data and I need to build the objects manually.

Comment: **Short answer**: Fact is a parameter-less theory.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Assuming that your `[AutoMoqData]` attribute looks something like this:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    internal AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

Then, **yes**, those two tests are equivalent.

Both `[Fact]` and `[Theory]` attributes are defined by xUnit.net.

The `[Fact]` attribute is used by the xUnit.net test runner to identify a 'normal' unit test: a test method that takes no method arguments.

The `[Theory]` attribute, on the other, expects one or more `DataAttribute` instances to supply the values for a [Parameterized Test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html)'s method arguments.

xUnit.net itself supplies various attributes that derive from `DataAttribute`: `[InlineData]`, `[ClassData]`, `[PropertyData]`.

AutoFixture hooks into this extensibility point of xUnit.net by supplying the `[AutoData]` attribute. It can be used to make tests more declarative.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yes, my AutoMoqData-Attribute looks like yours. BTW: I like your "Dependency Injection in .NET Book and my "Testproject" is build on it!

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson No, `AutoDataAttribute` is defined in *AutoFixture.XUnit* and *AutoFixture.XUnit2*.

Comment: Is it just me that finds the terms not to be clear ? they are `Test`s, but to me a `Fact` and a `Theory` are very different. You might test a theory, but not a fact ... dunno ... language is har d...

Comment: @Noctis To be honest, I, too, find the terms *fact* and *theory* somewhat contrived, but that's the naming choice made by the *xUnit.net* team...

Answer (score 13):

*Facts* are tests which are always true. They test invariant conditions.

*Theories* are tests which are only true for a particular set of data.

source: https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netfx/visual-studio